# Refresh tab onTabReselected Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview

I have a tabbed fragment application which essentially loads a webview. Within any given tab, you can navigate to further links. Basically, when the tab is **reselected**, I would like the webview to go back to the original webview url. I've tried using the onTabReselected method, but haven't had any success yet.

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {      

}
```

I've tried this replace line of code, just like in the onTabSelected method, but it doesn't seem to work. I've tried removing the fragment and then replacing the fragment, but that leaves me with an empty tab. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detaching and reattaching the fragment ending up being what I needed.

```
@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {      
    ft.detach(fragment);
    ft.attach(fragment);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To trigger support library v4 tab's onCreateView when onTabReselected triggered,

```
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            // specify tab position (optional)
            if (tab.getPosition()==0){
                // get adapter
                CustomViewPagerAdapter adapter =
                  ((CustomViewPagerAdapter) viewPager.getAdapter());

                // get fragment
                android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment = 
                    adapter.getRegisteredFragment(tab.getPosition());

                getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .detach(fragment)
                    .attach(fragment)
                    .commit();
            }

        }
```

registeredFragments variable simply holds fragment instances in CustomFragmentPagerAdapter class.

```
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Fragment fragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
        registeredFragments.put(position, fragment);
        return fragment;
    }
    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        registeredFragments.remove(position);
        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
    }
    public Fragment getRegisteredFragment(int position) {
        return registeredFragments.get(position);
    }
```